# Setting up socks proxy in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, socks

I am writing an android application that needs to access a service via **socks** proxy. I looked up the android [emulator documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) and found out that it supports http proxy but I didn't find any mention about socks proxy. I tried setting up the socks proxy while making the Http connection but that didn't work either. Here is my code snippet:

```
    SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("socks.foo.com", 1080);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);
    URL urlObj = new URL(url);
    URLConnection urlConn = urlObj.openConnection(proxy);
    InputStream in = urlConn.getInputStream();
```

Has anyone tried using socks proxy from android emulator? Any clues/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the emulator to use SOCKS, or the app? The title says one, the content the other.

Comment: I need the application to make connection via SOCKS. I thought it would be an emulator setting to redirect all traffic through SOCKS (like http proxy).

Comment: @Jollyjagga..have you found any solution of connecting to SOCKS in android application??

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [proxy support in Android is very buggy](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9126). However, according to the [network system properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ProxySelector.html) (get/set via Java, not UI), setting socksProxyHost and
socksProxyPort (default: 1080) in your app should work.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello